# How can I fix my dotfiles that prevent pulseaudio from working?

Tags: arch-linux, pulseaudio, i3, dot-files

I am currently using arch with i3-gaps. I just moved my `/home/` directory to a separate partition. Now pulseaudio no longer works. I think that the problem is related to my dotfiles in my `/home/` directory. They may be protected from non-root use or they may be corrupted. What might be the problem and how do I fix it? Which files should I try to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried just uninstalling pulseaudio and deleting my old configuration files for pulseaudio, and then I reinstalled the package, and that solved all of my problems.